# Is this the expected behavior

Tags: r

My apologies if this is kind of vague question as I am new to R. While experimenting with R I found one weird behavior. When I create a function like:

```
myfunction <- function(a,b){
    print(a,b)
}
```

and call it like:

```
myfunction(b = 10, a = 20)
```

it returns with result 20, but if I simply call it without function via assigning it directly to variables like:

```
a <- 20
b <- 10
print(a, b)
```

I get an error:

> ```
> Error in print.default(a, b) : invalid 'digits' argument
> ```

Furthermore I have read that printing multiple variables in the same line can be accomplished via:

```
sprintf("%i %i",a, b)
```

So here is it a bug that it is appearing in function call with result as the first argument?

Comment: `print(c(a,b))` works fine for me

Comment: The second parameter of `print.default` is `digits`, which is where that error is coming from. Really you rarely need `print` in R; just use the bare variable names like `a; b`. That won't work at the end of a function, though, which can only return one object (directly, anyway), so put them in a vector or list.

Comment: @alistaire can you reproduce the error via `print(a, b)`?

Comment: I can only get the error if I set `b` greater than 22: (hint, see `?print.default` and search for "digit").  I don't get an error with `b` equal to 10

Comment: @Sotos With `print(20, 10)` no, but `print(20, 100)` does the trick. That might be OS-dependent, though?

Comment: @BenBolker, Yup, that cleared it.

Comment: Am I wrong if I say you don't `print(a,b)`, you `paste(a,b)` ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It might be revealing some underlying differences in how parameters are being handled in different scenarios but I don't think it's a bug.

If your intention is to print both values, consider changing:

```
print(a,b)
```

To something like:

```
print(paste(a,b))
```

From `?print.default`:

```
# S3 method for default
print(x, digits = NULL, quote = TRUE,
  na.print = NULL, print.gap = NULL, right = FALSE,
  max = NULL, useSource = TRUE, …)

x       the object to be printed.

digits  a non-null value for digits specifies the minimum number of 
        significant digits to be printed in values. The default, NULL, uses 
        getOption("digits"). (For the interpretation for complex numbers see 
        signif.) Non-integer values will be rounded down, and only values 
        greater than or equal to 1 and no greater than 22 are accepted.
...
```

So R is expecting everything that you actually want to print to be contained in the first variable (`x`).

Based on your results and some of the comments, apparently in some cases the second variable is being accepted as a valid `digits` parameter value and in other cases it is not.

While this is a little odd, the more important point is that `print(a,b)` is not a syntactically correct way to print multiple values.