# NAs produced by Coercion Error and Invalid Printing Digits

Tags: r

I have a function called Quote.Annuity, which takes no parameters. I prompt the user with a series of questions, such as "What is your Name", "DOB?", et cetera. I made sure to define my variables properly as either characters or numeric. In this case of a numeric like Payment amount being entered with commas, I utilized gsub() to obviate possible issues. But I receive an error about Forced Coercion and Invalid Printing Digits. Would appreciate it if someone could give me an idea of where in my code I made this mistake.

Side Note: actPV() is previous function I already created

```
Quote.annuity <- function() {
library(lubridate)


    variable_beg <- readline("Do you want an annuity quote? (Yes/No)")
    variable_beg <- as.character(variable_beg)

   if(variable_beg == "No") {
       print("Bye")
    }

   while(variable_beg == "Yes") {


my.name <- readline("Enter name: ")
my.name <- as.character(my.name)

my.DOB <- readline("Enter DOB: ")
my.DOB <- as.Date(my.DOB)
##convDOB <- ?lubridate::mdy(my.DOB)
diffDays = Sys.Date() - my.DOB
age = round(diffDays/365)


my.gender <- readline("Enter Gender(Male/Female): ")
my.gender <- as.character(my.gender)

my.payment <- readline("Enter Payment amount: ")
my.payment <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", my.payment))

my.interestRate <- readline("Choose either of two interest rates: 0.05 (5%) or 0.1 (10%)")
my.interestRate <- as.numeric(my.interestRate)

annuity <- my.payment * actPV(a = age, g = my.gender, r = my.interestRate)

print(my.name, " your expected annuity present value is ", mean(annuity))
break()
}


 } # End function
```

Comment: What input are you putting into your function? I could not reproduce the same error.

Comment: I just typed in my name. Selected a random DOB like 01/01/2002, selected Female for Gender, 0.05 for Interest Rate and 100,000 for payment. The function itself has no parameters.

Comment: `as.Date("01/01/2002")` will not give you the output you expect.

Answer (score 1):

See [Is this the expected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607864/is-this-the-expected-behavior/49742452) for an explanation.
The answer is that you print expects a digit. So you have to enclose your arguments in `paste` or `paste0`. Try[not tested],

```
print(paste0(my.name, " your expected annuity present value is ", mean(annuity)))
```